# Server doesn't parse php code fully

Tags: php, apache, server, apache2

Since a few days my server doesn't parse my php code (not only the attached file) anymore. If I call the php file via a html file it will just load forever.
The code is tested on a local apache2 server and there it works fine. I already tried to reinstall php5/apache2 on the server but still no progress.

The servers runs Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = "placeholder@placeholder.com";

$email_subject = "Website Contact";


function died($error) {

    // your error code can go here

    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

    echo $error."<br /><br />";

    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

    die();

}



// validation expected data exists

if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['email']) ||

    !isset($_POST['message'])) {

    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');

}


$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



function clean_string($string) {

  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}



$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";

$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";


// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);


?>
<html>
<p>Succesful!</p>
</body>

</html>

<?php

}

?>
```

´

Comment: Is it as simple as you have not closed the first IF statement i.e. No `}`

Comment: Have you checked php error reporting and Apache error.log? What do you see there?

Comment: The more you look at this code the more I am surprised you think it ever ran correctly

Comment: I didn't create the code by myself. The problem isn't the code itself, it must be a server side problem as it cannot execute any php code correctly (example: forum registration doesn't work)..

Answer (score 0):

Define your function outside any if statements. Not sure this is the reason for your error but it at least reads more logically. Also indent your code sensibly it helps a lot when looking for errors.

Also `<p>` tags belong on the `<body` and not in the `<html>` section of your HTML code.

Also if you have issues on a LIVE server, add some error reporting to your script, remember on Live servers errors are only written to logs, write then to the screen while you fox a bug its easier to see whats going wrong

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here

    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}


if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_to = "placeholder@placeholder.com";
    $email_subject = "Website Contact";

    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
               'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
               'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
}
?>
<html>    
<body>
    <p>Succesful!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The main problem isn't script. As I mentioned I can easily execute it on another server.

Comment: Are you running the `.html` by double clicking on the file name using explorer??

Comment: So are you calling this `.php` file from a `<form>` in a `.html` file